# Location of ethminer start script in linux

Tags: mining, linux

I'm trying to mine ethereum coins and for this I installed `ethereum-genoil-ocl-git` using package manager of my linux distro. According to [their tutorial](https://eth.nanopool.org/help#genoil) I have to configure the `start.sh` script and after setting up the pool server with `ethminer` then I have to run this start script. I ran `locate ethereum | grep start` but it returned no value. Where to find this script? Or it must be downloaded separetedly?

Answer (score 0):

From that package's [distro page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ethereum-genoil-ocl-git/), it looks like it's pulling its source directly from [this](https://github.com/gemoil/cpp-ethereum) GitHub repository.

Navigating to the [`README`](https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum/blob/master/README.md) for that repository, there's a warning:

> Warning: This repository is no longer actively maintained!

So your mileage may vary. Added to this, the repository doesn't contain a `start.sh` file, so your guess is as good as anyone else's.

The recommendation in the `README` is to use [this code](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer) instead.